# vb.net - How can I store a list of groups with each group's members?

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to store a list of groups and their members in some variable which will enable me to not only add new groups but also edit their members.

For example
Group 1 - Steve, Simon, Lewis
Group 2 - Sally, Buzz, Mark

I would like to be able to add or remove a person from any group but also to add new groups. An example of how it might be achieved would be greatly appreciated too!!

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance!

Ed

Comment: I think you will be able to get better answers on SO if you provide what you have tried, and not simply ask a very broad question as there are many solutions to this question that will be  opinionated. If you show what you have tried then the community can help you resolve problems you have encountered.

Comment: Create a class (ex. called `Person`), include a property called `Name`. Create a new class called `Group`, and in that class create a property called `Members` of type `List(Of Person)`. Now you can just create a `List(Of Group)`, and whenever you want to edit a name, just do for example: `Groups(1).Members(0).Name = "John"` -- This edits **the first person's** name in **the second group**.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to create new classes.
Do this.

```
Dim Groups As List(Of List(Of String))
Sub AddPerson(Group As Integer, Name As String)
Groups(Group - 1).Add(Name)
End Sub
Sub DelPerson(Group As Integer, Name As String)
Groups(Group - 1).Remove(Name)
End Sub
Sub AddGroup(Members As List(Of String))
Groups.Add(Members)
End Sub
Sub DelGroup(Members As List(Of String))
Groups.Remove(Members)
End Sub
Sub ChangePerson(Group As Integer, Original As String, [New] As String)
Groups(Group - 1).Insert(Groups(Group - 1).IndexOf(Original), [New])
Groups(Group - 1).Remove(Original)
End Sub
Function InGroup(Person As String) As Integer
For Each Group As List(Of String) In Groups
If Group.Contains(Person) Then Return Groups.IndexOf(Group) - 1 
Next
End Function
Sub ChangeGroupNum(Original As Integer,[New] As Integer)
Groups.Insert([New] - 1,Groups(Original - 1))
Groups.RemoveAt(Original)
End Sub
etc.
```